# SQL Select That Appear More than Once with Different ID

Tags: sql

I have a large table with a large amount of columns but for this I will only be interested in 3 columns, so my date is as below.

```
PartNumber  BrandID PartTerminonogyID
1234AD      343
DD93873 DAB 343
1-8383-343  STE 4424
444 OTE 5656
444 NYT 4543
3434    IDY 4543
64545   IDH 3455
64545   IDH 8585
```

What I want is to find each PartNumber/BrandID combo that has more than one PartTerminologyID

Keep in mind that I cannot sure part number alone as different manufacturers may have the same part number for completely different items.  So the identifier is PartNumber/BrandID combo, you can think of this as a SKU if that helps.  And what I want is to see all cases where the same SKU has more than one PartTerminologyID.  I would like to see each PartTerminologyID with the results as well.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Look up the "group by" and "having count(*) > 1" commands.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following which implements a `HAVING` clause and a `GROUP BY`:

```
select partnumber, brandid, PartTerminonogyID
from yourtable t
where exists (select partnumber, brandid
              from yourtable t1
              where t.partnumber = t1.partnumber
                and t.brandid = t1.brandid
              group by partnumber, brandid
              having count(distinct PartTerminonogyID) >1);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a2dc/5)

If you want to include additional tables, then you will just `JOIN` them:

```
select t.partnumber, t.brandid, t.PartTerminonogyID, p.partTerminologyName 
from yourtable t
inner join parts p
  on t.PartTerminonogyID = p.PartTerminonogyID
where exists (select partnumber, brandid
              from yourtable t1
              where t.partnumber = t1.partnumber
                and t.brandid = t1.brandid
              group by partnumber, brandid
              having count(distinct PartTerminonogyID) >1);
```

Comment: One more thing.  I want to do a lookup to table parts to get the partTerminologyName and add that to the result.

Comment: @user2030553 you will just add a join to the other table. See my edit

Comment: Actually no this is not working.  It gives me same exact results multiple times

Comment: @user2030553 can you edit the sql fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a2dc/5) with your tables and some sample data?